# :not selector in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to style the text in all elements of a HTML document except the ones nested in a specific class. I have no control over the HTML, I can only modify the CSS.

Here is a piece of code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column c1">
    <div class="text">
      text in column 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column c2">
    <div class="text">
      text in column 2
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="column c3">
    <div class="text">
      text in column 3
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I want all `text` elements, except the ones in a `c1` element, to be bold. I don't know in advance how many columns there can be.

I've tried the following CSS that makes use of the `:not` selector, but it renders everything bold:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

:not(.c1) .text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Why isn't the `:not` selector working? What am I doing wrong?
[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucrus/w3y9x0y7/) to try out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `:not(.c1)` will select any element that doesn't have that class. That can be the `.container` too.

Either add a direct child combinator:

```
:not(.c1) > .text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or use the other class as well:

```
.column:not(.c1) .text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w3y9x0y7/1/). You have to declare the `column` class.

This does the job:

```
.column:not(.c1) .text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Although it should be noted that the reason why `:not(.c1) .text` doesn't work is that, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not), `:not(foo){}` will match anything that isn't foo, **including `<html>` and `<body>`**, so it will match `.container .text`, `html .text` and `body .text`.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to switch from a descendant to a child combinator.

In other words, from this:

```
:not(.c1) .text
```

To this:

```
:not(.c1) > .text
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/w3y9x0y7/2/)

---

Your selector...

```
:not(.c1) .text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
*:not(.c1) .text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This selector says:

> *select an element with class `text` that is a descendant of any other element, except an element with class `c1`*.

Okay, well, `.text` is a descendant of a `div` with class `c1` in one instance – so it gets excluded as you intend. But `.text` is also a descendant of `html`, `body` and `.container`. So the rule fails to work as you expect because it satisfies multiple scenarios.

Instead, try this:

```
:not(.c1) > .text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This selector says:

> *select an element with class `text` when the parent element does not have the class `c1`*.

Answer (score -2):

This can work too :

```
 .column:not(.c1) .text {
      font-weight: bold;
  }
```

Comment: That's nonsense. A pseudo-class *is* a selector. A pseudo-class is a simple selector, just like an id selector or a class selector or a type selector. And therefore a pseudo-class *can* be used alone, without having to be qualified with any other simple selector.

Comment: damned ! the fact that it's working too if you simply add a selector before totally measled me. Thank's for correcting me