# How to use the :not() selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a html template:

```html
<div class="table-vertical">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="picker">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And I use styles for this table:

```css
.table-vertical,
.table-vertical tbody,
.table-vertical thead,
.table-vertical td,
.table-vertical tr {
  display: block;
}
```

But I need to ignore the second table inside `td` element and class `.picker`, so I tried:

```css
.table-vertical,
.table-vertical :not(.picker) tbody,
.table-vertical thead,
.table-vertical :not(.picker) td,
.table-vertical :not(.picker) tr {
      display: block;
}
```

But this does not work. So how to ignore second table inside td and div?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `:not()` selectors actually work. The problem is your selectors are structured to satisfy multiple scenarios.

Here's an example:

```
.table-vertical :not(.picker) tbody
```

`tbody` is a descendant of `.picker`, so it is excluded.

But, `tbody` is also a descendant of `.table-vertical`, so it is included.

This is the reason your `:not()` selectors aren't applying. They are overridden by the selectors that do apply.

Try this approach:

- There are two table elements in your HTML structure.
- One is a child of `.table-vertical`
- The other is a child of `.picker`
- So, target only the child of `.picker` for exclusion.

```css
.table-vertical,
.table-vertical :not(.picker) > table {
  display: block;
  background: aquamarine !important;
}

.table-vertical {
  padding: 5px;
}

.table {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.picker {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.picker,
.picker * {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-vertical">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>primary table</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="picker">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>picker table</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

For another take on this scenario, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353253/3597276

Comment: I think op has `.table-vertical, .table-vertical :not(.picker) tbody,.table-vertical thead,.table-vertical :not(.picker) td, .table-vertical :not(.picker) tr`

Comment: @DanielH, yes, you're right. I pasted the code into jsFiddle. Then I hit "tidy", which removed the spaces!

Comment: =D yeah, jsFiddle should fix that!

Comment: Okay, answer revised. @DanielH